# How to Broadcast a message to a pubsub node using C# XMPP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xmpp, openfire

I am using [.NET API for XMPP](https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) to send messages to my users registered on Openfire Server.

What I want now is to send a Broadcast to all the members of a node. I've searched it on internet but found nothing.

1. I want to register a pubsub node(group)  and join members in that group.
2. Then, I want to broadcast a message to all of them in a single go.

All I can find on official site is [THIS](https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/SendMessage). Can anybody help ? Or any link that may help??

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

1. i sugguest using [agsxmpp](http://www.ag-software.net/agsxmpp-sdk/)
2. openfire has a plugin named ["broadcast"](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/broadcast/readme.html),it is available to download on openfire's Admin Controlpanel "http://yourdomain.com:9090/available-plugins.jsp"
3. after installing this plugin and restart openfire, you can send  a broadcast
   to all online users with to="all@broadcast.yourdomain.com",  or to a group with to="groupname@broadcast.yourdomain.com"